# SED incorrectly replaces only the first instance of a pattern on a line

Tags: bash, sed

Hello: I have tab separated data of the form
customer-item description-purchase price-category

e.g. a.out contains:

```
1\t400 Bananas\t3.00\tfruit
2\t60 Oranges\t0.00\tfruit
3\tNULL\t3.0\tfruit
4\tCarrots\tNULL\tfruit
5\tNULL\tNULL\tfruit
```

I'm attempting to get rid of all the NULL fields. I can't rely on the simple replacement of the string "NULL" as it may be a substring; so I am attempting

```
sed -i 's:\tNULL\t:\t\t:g' a.out
```

when I do this, I end up with

```
1\t400 Bananas\t3.00\tfruit
2\t60 Oranges\t0.00\tfruit
3\t\t3.0\tfruit
4\tCarrots\t\tfruit
5.\t\tNULL\tfruit
```

what's wrong here is that #5 has only suffered a replacement of the first instance of the search string on each line.

If I run my sed command twice, I end up with the result I want:

```
1\t400 Bananas\t3.00\tfruit
2\t60 Oranges\t0.00\tfruit
3\t\t3.0\tfruit
4\tCarrots\t\tfruit
5.\t\t\tfruit
```

where you can see that line 5 has both  of the NULLs removed 
But I don't understand why I'm suffering this?

Comment: I believe the matches are cumulative. Each starting with the end of the previous match. So your first match eats the trailing `\t` and so the second match cannot see it.

Comment: An answer to a question not asked: `sed -i ':A;s:\\tNULL\\t:\\t\\t:;tA' a.out`

Comment: @Cyrus why not post that as an answer?

Comment: In addition to the one problem the OP found in their code it also  won't handle `NULL` in the last field. This being because `NULL` would be followed by `$` (end of line) instead of a `tab`

Comment: @Cyrus is correct. I didn't point out that there was no prospect of null in the last column in a row. Apologies

Comment: @Cyrus: I see how :t does this for me in this situation, but I had understood that the /g modifier on the substitution command would do things globally, rather than only the first on a given line.

I'd welcome the explanation of why /g wasn't working for me.

Comment: It does do it globally on the line, but there is a catch. It does it in a single pass. So your solution would see `5\tNULL\tNULL\tfruit` and find the first `\tNULL\t` matches and it would output `\t\t`. with `/g` it will continue in the buffer with the next unprocessed characters which would be `NULL\t`. The problem is that there is no `\t` in front of the second NULL because we ate it processing the previous one since it was processed as the end delimiter. From our perspective it appears to skip the second one.

Comment: When I gave my solution I didn't assume there was no prospect of it being NULL in the final field, so I had assumed you may have missed it. Thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: @lurker: I think dhk had a comprehension question.

Answer (score 3):

Since tabs can't be inside strings in your case since that would imply a new field you might be able to do what you want simply by doing this;

```
sed ':start ; s/\tNULL\(\t\|$\)/\t\1/ ; t start' a.out
```

First the inner part `s/\tNULL\(\t\|$\)/\t\1/` searches for `tab` `NULL` followed by a `tab` or end of line `$` and replace with a `tab` followed by the character that did appear after `NULL` (this last part is done using `\1`). We'll call that `expression`

We now have:

```
sed ':start ; expression ; t start' a.out
```

This is effectively a loop (like goto). :start is a label. `;` acts as a statement delimiter. I have described what expression does above. `t start` says that IF the expression did any substitution that a jump will be made to label `start`. The buffer will contain the *substituted* text. This loop occurs until no substitution can be done on the line and then processing continues.

Information on sed flow control and other useful tidbits can be found [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-59)

Comment: The problem with that is that it assumes that I don't have a text field with a word like, say any of the following: (which I just discovered):

- Nullifiers
- Nulliparas
- Nullipores

Comment: Good point I amended my expression accordingly. It now looks for NULL preceded by a tab and proceeded by a tab or end of line.

Comment: This has the same problem of not handling `\tNULL\tNULL\t` correctly.

Comment: Thanks John, I have made the final adjustment (I hope) by simply adding a loop to sed to continue doing substitutions on each line until none remain.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if ($i == "NULL") {
            $i = "";
        }
    }
    print
}' test.txt
```

The straightforward solution is to use `\t` as a field separator and then loop over all of the fields looking for an exact match of `"NULL"`. No substringing.

Here's the same thing as a one liner:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if($i=="NULL") $i=""} 1' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` makes it simpler:

```
awk -F '\tNULL\\>' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1' file
1\t400 Bananas\t3.00\tfruit
2\t60 Oranges\t0.00\tfruit
3\t\t3.0\tfruit
4\tCarrots\t\tfruit
5\t\t\tfruit
```

Comment: As the OP pointed out to me NULL can be part of a substring. This was something I missed in his question. So if you put `NULLify` in a field awk would return `ify`

Comment: ok check updated answer with word boundary to avoid matching `NULLify`

Answer (score 0):

From `grep(1)` on a recent Linux:

**The Backslash Character and Special Expressions**

The  symbols  \<  and  >  respectively  match  the empty string at the
beginning and end of a word.  The symbol \b matches the empty string at
the  edge  of a word [...]

--

So, how about:

```
sed -i 's:\<NULL\>::g' a.out
```

Comment: One of the problems would be if `NULL` appeared in a string like `6\tNULL wants to be NULL\t2ndfield` where \t is a `tab` character. Your solution would see space as a word delimiter as well and output `6\t wants to be \t2ndfield`. Spaces in the text aren't word boundaries - only end of line `$` and `tab`

Comment: Ah - good catch, @MichaelPetch - chalk mine up as a "clear, simple, and wrong" solution. I've voted for yours, although I do find the `awk`-based solution of @JohnKugelman a more straightforward read. But the OP did say `sed`...